# MigraDoc PdfDocumentRenderer.RenderDocument takes too long/freezes with some images

Tags: c#, rendering, migradoc

Within MigraDoc I am adding an image to a paragraph and rendering. All seems fine until (I assume) the files start to get a bit larger. It doesn't seem to be specific to any format. I was able to add a jpg of size (300x300) no problem and the document rendered in a split second. I then try with another file (569x709) and it just seems to hang on rendering.

I have had it stuck on rendering for 10 mins now and still nothing. When I escape out of debugging I am finding that the image on file is also locked and I can do nothing with it unless I restart my computer.

I am adding the Image to a paragraph simply using:

```
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image image = paragraph.AddImage(fileLocation).Clone();
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can look at or supply any more info.

Comment: I should add that this is using MigraDoc GDI Version 1.32.4334

Comment: Why do you invoke `Clone()`? Makes no sense with the snippet you are showing. If the issue can be replicated with the current 1.50 RC1 then please use the IssueSubmissionTemplate so we can investigate the issue. If it works with 1.50 RC1 then the issue was already resolved in the past five years - and you can try to update the source code of 1.32 with the bug fix from version 1.50. You can compile against the source code of version 1.32 to see where it hangs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had been getting an error when rendering previously suggesting I can only apply a Clone to get the Image Object. I have today however updated to the new 1.50 RC1 and am using the Memory Stream example - however I am getting the same result. When adding some images it just seems to hang on Rendering. You mentioned using the IssueSubmissionTemplate above... How might I go about that?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the link: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/IssueSubmissions.ashx

Comment: Thanks again... was just looking at that now. I will see if I can get this done soon. One question, I cannot see at the moment how I submit this project once I have it replicating my problem?

Comment: Okay, so I have recreated my code on the sample project and it all seems to work fine there! There are a lot of other factors to my (MVC) application here but on the face of it there isn't anything glaringly obvious that could be causing my problem?! I guess this is back with me then!??

Comment: With the IssueSubmissionTemplate you can test all three builds (Core, GDI+, WPF). The template is not mandatory, so if it has to MVC to replicate the issue then that will be OK. Just try to make it "minimal" - if "minimal" requires 1000 pages of "Lorem ipsum" and 1000 images then we'll have to deal with it. But MVC/IIS should have little (rather no) impact on the generation of the PDF file.